# Find all solutions of the IVP $ty' = y$, $y(t_0) = y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $ty' = y$, $y(t_0) = y_0$. Find all pairs $(t_0,y_0)$ such that the equation has:
a) no solution
b) a unique solution

So I know that by the uniqueness theorem, since $g(t)=0$ is continuous for all $t$ and $p(t)=-1/t$ is continuous for $t\not=0$, then given any $(t_0,y_0)$ where $t_0 \not=0$, there is always a unique solution.
However, what about when $t_0=0$? Do I actually solve the equation?

Comment: Hint: $$\left(\frac{y}t\right)'=\frac{ty'-y}{t^2}=0$$

Comment: Sorry, I not sure I understand. This tells me that $y = ct$, where $c$ is the constant of integration? Does this mean that plugging in $t_0=0$ gives us $y_0=0$? But what actually is the solution?

Comment: Yes this tells you that every solution $y$ is such that $y(t)/t$ is constant when defined. Now it is up to you to apply this fact to your setting.

Comment: Doesn't this mean there are infinite solutions? In othere words, $y=ct$ and $c$ can be anything?

Comment: Hint: Read your question.